# Flutter SharedPreferences getInstance return null

Tags: flutter, dart

Although I set the _sharedPreferences in the constructor, it gets null in getUsername. I don't know missing what:

```
  class PreferencesProvider {
  SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  PreferencesProvider() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => _sharedPreferences = prefs);
  }

  String getUsername() {
    return _sharedPreferences.getString("Username");
  }

  String getX() {
    return _sharedPreferences.getString("X");
  }

  String getY() {
    return _sharedPreferences.getString("Y");
  }

  String getZ() {
    return _sharedPreferences.getString("Z");
  }
}
```

alternatively it didn't work either:

```
class LoginProvider {
  SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  LoginProvider._internal();
  static final LoginProvider _instance = LoginProvider._internal();

  factory LoginProvider() {
    _instance.initPreferences();
    return _instance;
  }

  initPreferences() async {
    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

I want to use this in MaterialApp:

```
initialRoute: PreferencesProvider().isLoggedIn() ? "MainPage" : "LoginPage"
```

Edit: I know I should use await. But then keyword isn't same? I don't want to wait the instance again for all returns. In the other hand, I can't use await in initialRoute.

Answer (score 2):

The way i manage to login the user for my application for the similar scenario is,

```
String startPage="LoginPage";
void main() {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String user=prefs.getString("Username");
  if(user!=null && user.length>0){
    startPage="MainPage";
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now, set your **initialRoute** as follow,

```
initialRoute: startPage,
```

This solution works in every scenario because i am fetching the data before the runApp() function in my application. Your application renders your initialPage after calling the runApp() function.

This is the best way to manage your login page based on data retrieval from the sharedpreferences as SharedPreferences takes time to fetch the data. Till the data is retrieved from sharedpreferences your build method gets completed its UI rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait a little bit for get username from shared preferences. getInstance is an async process.

Below code will work, because `getString` will work after `getInstance`

```
Future<String> getUsername() async {
  _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return _sharedPreferences.getString("Username");
}
```

You need to modify your `PreferencesProvider` class

Comment: Is the `getInstance()` needed only because `getUsername` is called immediately after creating the class `PreferencesProvider ` and thus `_sharedPreferences` is still `null` (before Future gives it a value), or is the `getInstance()` also needed in all the other methods (`getY`, `getX` and `getZ`)? In other words, `getInstance` provides the current data snapshot, or is the info updated to `_sharedPreferences` without calling it again?

Answer (score 0):

While using preferences you should use `Future`, `await` and `async`

```
Future<String> getUsername() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String storeUserDetails = prefs.getString("Username");
    return (storeUserDetails != null);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting null after calling getUsername() function using 

getusername().then((value) => username = value);